# Literal string search is destroyed by filtered short words

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Example:

- [c# +reflection +"create array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+%2Breflection+%2B%22create+array%22&submit=search) yields 0 results.
- [c# +reflection +"create an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+%2Breflection+%2B%22create+an+array%22&submit=search) yields 24 results.
- [c# +reflection +"create and array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+%2breflection%20%2b%22create+and+array%22&submit=search) yields the same 24 results.
- [c# +reflection +"create or array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+%2breflection%20%2b%22create+or+array%22&submit=search) yields the same 24 results as well.

Such ignored words cleary break the phrase search (also visible in the highlighting).

Also can someone explain how adding `title:` results in no results?

- [c# +reflection +title:"create an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+%2Breflection+%2Btitle%3A%22create+an+array%22&submit=search) should at least turn up [How to create an array of enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160267/how-to-create-an-array-of-enums).

Comment: I don't have an answer for your first question, but the second one is easy. The word "reflection" doesn't appear in that question, so why should it return it?

Comment: @CodyGray: Well, all the above queries return that answer, which also require the word reflection. (Also the word can be found in the answers, i did not restrict reflection to the question)

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** as part of [the latest search changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), phrase searches are now **exact** matches, and you no longer need the `+` sign as we're an **AND** search by default now.  Here are the updated searches from your question:

- [c# reflection "create array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c#%20reflection%20%22create%20array%22) yields 4 results.
- [c# reflection "create an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c#%20reflection%20%22create%20an%20array%22) yields 22 results.
- [c# reflection "create and array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c#%20reflection%20%22create%20and%20array%22) yields 0 results.
- [c# reflection "create or array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c#%20reflection%20%22create%20or%20array%22) yields 0 results.

---

`title:` searches **only questions** (we say this in the help here: https://stackoverflow.com/search), that's why your last example doesn't return that result..."reflection" isn't in *the question*.  If you think it should behave differently, throw up a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), we'll be taking a hard look at search very soon.

<s>As for the others, we can take a look, stop words are a very difficult problem. I can't make any promises there but we'll see what we can do.</s>