# The "title:" search option should not affect all search keywords

Tags: feature-request, search

As suggested in [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123411/156560) to one of my questions, I request that the `title:` search option be more limited in scope, which I think would make the semantics more intuitive.

Currently, this operator will restrict all search terms to the question. According to the [documentation for the search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search):

> The above options can be freely combined in any order with the exception of `title:` and `body:`, these will operate on all following terms

For example, if I were to search for...

- `+parse +html +regex`
  then all terms must appear in the question or answers to that question.
- `+parse +title:html +regex`
  then all terms must appear in the question, even though only `html` has this question-related option.

Comment: I support this feature request. Despite the fact that the stipulation appears in the documentation, the syntax is quite confusing. It's unclear why the `title:` operator would have the special associativity that it does.

Comment: +1 for not intuitive at all.